# how to alter table Composite primary key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, composite-primary-key

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS]
([DEPARTMENT_CODE] [varchar](3) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 [IM_INV_NO] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
 [LOCATION_CODE] [varchar](2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 [CURR_QTY] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__INVS_ITEM__CURR___1352D76D]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 [DO_QTY] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__INVS_ITEM__DO_QT__1446FBA6]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 [ALLOC_QTY] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__INVS_ITEM__ALLOC__153B1FDF]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 [YOB_QTY] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__INVS_ITEM__YOB_Q__162F4418]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 [FOC_QTY] [numeric](10, 0) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__INVS_ITEM__FOC_Q__17236851]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 [USER_CREATED] [varchar](25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 [DATE_CREATED] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [USER_MODIFIED] [varchar](25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [DATE_MODIFIED] [datetime] NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS_PK] 
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DEPARTMENT_CODE] ASC,
 [IM_INV_NO] ASC, [LOCATION_CODE] ASC)
 WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is my table structure ......how can I remove the composite primary key in table and also I should add foreign key to im_inv_no reference table is invs_location which contain im_inv_no and the department_code should be same primary key .pls help

Comment: Please, try to add the useful and relevant tags like "sql-server-2005" to your next question right away. It gives people a better idea of what you're using and what to tell you for assistance!

Comment: You are planning to put some primary key on the table, right? and if the fileds in your composite key whould be unique, when you remove the primary key at a minimum you should put a unique index onthem or you will have data integrity problems in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove your composite primary key, use:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS
  DROP CONSTRAINT INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS_PK
```

To add a foreign key, use this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_INV_NO_REFERENCE
  FOREIGN KEY(IM_INV_NO, DEPARTMENT_CODE)
  REFERENCES dbo.invs_location(IM_INV_NO, DEPARTMENT_CODE)
```

These are all **really basic** beginner SQL questions - I would **strongly** recommend you read one of the various good SQL tutorials out there to get used to SQL first, before posting each and every single little question here....

[W3Schools SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/default.asp)

Marc

Comment: OK, then do the right thing and accept the answer! Be a good SO citizen to get answers in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You can create new tables with modifications you need, copy your data then renaming new talbes to the same names as old tables and deleting old ones. It is probably the most efficient way as well.

Comment: Using the ALTER TABLE command is the most efficient way. However, using the "create copy and rename" methodology would be the least disruptive way (i.e. locks/downtime), if you were working on a Production database.